# Image positioning in gallery with css

Tags: html, css

I'm new to css.
I have created a gallery with 6 images.
I have chose float: left.
My issue is, the pictures are all on same line as each other.
I want to have 3 on top and 3 below.
How do I make this happen? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this so it depends on what fits your needs.

You can add a <kbd>`<br>`</kbd> tag right after the 3rd image to display a new line. (or wrap the new line in a paragraph `<p><!-- code --></p>`).

Another way is wrapping your content in a [`block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) element. For example, a [DIV](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div).

Being that you're new to [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS) I suggest starting off with good coding practices.

My snippet below is for [RWD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design).

What I did is I wrapped my images in a div and used percents for the image size. By default images are displayed [inline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) this will not go in a new line. The only time this happens is when they can't fill the space in the container. (if you want to have it float left without going on a new line; you would use [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)`: nowrap`.

You may also want to take a look at [CodePen](http://codepen.io/). It's a community where they post live snippets of code that you can interact with (not to mention learn from). Plus [Codepen](http://codepen.io/) supports lots of [Preprocessors](http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/preprocessors/).

Hope this helps to get started.

```css
.images {
  text-align: center;
}

.images img {
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
  <img src="http://wallpapershdnow.com/download.php?f=animals/bears/baby-bears/baby-bear-wallpaper-4.jpg">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/3eouyHS.jpg">
  <img src="http://cdn4.teen.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/baby-polar-bears-main1.jpg">
  <img src="http://cdn1.theodysseyonline.com/files/2015/11/14/6358312506953272101532239493_l-Baby-bear.jpg">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/wYFHJNI.jpg">
  <img src="http://image.mlive.com/home/mlive-media/width960/img/grandrapidspress/photo/2015/03/20/-6328b3da95a15820.JPG">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have found the solution. I input a max width e.g width: 600px;    as each pic is 200px and that seemed to do it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

you can surround the images inside a `<div></div>` tag and set a width property or max-width on it or the other option is you can use `<br />` after each image to jump down to the next line.